# How to add value to particular part of python list?

Tags: python

**NOTE: My need isn't this e.g. `List[2:4] = 5`**

Suppose my `List=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

I want to **add 5** from index 2 to 4.

So the resultant List would be like List=[1,2,**8,9,10**,6]

If I have 2d array `List=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and want to **add 5** to col 1 `List=[[6,2,3],[9,5,6]]`then what would be the code?

Comment: `my_list = [n + 5 if i in range(2, 5) else n for i, n in enumerate(my_list)]`

Comment: @Samwise It's actually `range(2, 4)` :)

Comment: @AnnZen actually no, if you're going by their desired output (note that three items are incremented), because of how `range` works. :)  OP wants to add to every item in indices 2 to 4 *inclusive*.

Comment: Oh, thanks for informing me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution uses NumPy but my implementation is on an in-built list and other solutions are copying unnecessary elements.

So here I found the manual way to do it.

```
List = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
# for horizontal update
colToUpdate = 2
for r in range(0,2):
    A[r][colToUpdate] += add

# for vertical update
rowToUpdate = 1
for c in range(2,5):
    A[rowToUpdate][c] += add
```

Answer (score 1):

[Numpy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) can handle such slice operations:

```
import numpy as np

List = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
List[2:5] += 5
print(List)
```

Numpy will really come in handy for you if you have many of such tasks to do in your code. However, if it's just a one time thing in your code, you can do:

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(2, 5):
    List[i] += 5
print(List)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 6]
```

---

EDIT

Addressing [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66657427/2), you can also use numpy arrays like so:

```
import numpy as np

List = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
List[0] += 5
print(List)
```

Or using a loop:

```
List = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for i in range(len(List[0])):
    List[0][i] += 5
print(List)
```

Output:

```
[[6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Your answer is totally correct but can't accept it because my whole implementation is on the in-built list so...

Comment: @stackaayush I also have an answer for the built-in list, see the bottom of *"Or using a loop:"*

Answer (score 1):

One approach is

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
add_item = [2,3]
new_list = [x+1 if i in add_item else x for i, x in enumerate(my_list)]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done through **list comprehension**.

The following function takes a 2D array `2d`, a position index `i` and a value `v`, and adds `v` to the `i`-th element of each array.

```
def add_value(2d, i, v):
   return [array[:i] + [array[i]+v] + array[i+1:] for array in 2d]
```

So, calling the function on the list in your example:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
add_value(my_list,0,5)
```

Would print out the desired output:

```
>>> [[6, 2, 3], [9, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct but 2d array size is not fixed as I have shown (2 by 3). The size can be 1000 by 1000 and I want to update only part of that array. By your implementation, it will generate a new 2d array. And even more, it will traverse and copy the rest of the elements which should not be the part of updation.